# Disable NSMenuItem coupled to outlet with Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

How can I disable a NSMenuItem?
I try to disable a NSMenuItem after it has been clicked.
The click is handled correctly by the Action (Logout).

I tried changing the `Enabled` property to false in the following two ways:

```
partial void Logout (AppKit.NSMenuItem sender)
{
   sender.Enabled = false;
}
```

and

```
partial void Logout (AppKit.NSMenuItem sender)
{
   LogoutItemOutlet.Enabled = false;
}
```

But every time this action is called, the `Enabled` fields keep being `true`. The menu item itself also never actually disables.

How to disable the NSMenuItem after an action is executed?

Comment: Perhaps redrawing/refreshing after the disable would help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting menu item's `Action` to `null`:

```
partial void Logout (AppKit.NSMenuItem sender)
{
   LogoutItemOutlet.Action = null;

   // I don't think you need the following but it won't hurt
   LogoutItemOutlet.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work. I'm re-enabling the butting with `ObjCRuntime.Selector("NameOfAction:")`. Do you know if this is actually the correct way?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the correct way or not but an alternative way could be to subscribe/unsubscribe from Activated event: 

To disable `LogoutItemOutlet.Activated -= LogoutActivatedHandler;` and to enable `LogoutItemOutlet.Activated += LogoutActivatedHandler;`

Answer (score 0):

`NSMenuItem` `Enabled` property has no effect unless the `NSMenu` in which the item will be added or is already a part of has `AutoEnablesItems` set to `true` (it is `false` by default).  This property can be set programmatically, or in Interface Builder.

Comment: The setting in the Interface Builder is already enabled, also when debugging the `Menu` property of my NSStatusItem is already set to true.